# Visual Studio project not connected for debugging in the IDE

Tags: .net, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, sdk

I have a .NET based test automation framework, I cloned it from github inside Visual Studio 2022.

But somehow Im not able to perform common actions in VS.

I can't open the nuget manager window, view the project settings, run the project or debug with VS options.

I must use these commands in order to run it:

> dotnet build {project.sln path}

> dotnet test {project.dll path}

Do you know a way to solve this, a way to export it or create a new project maybe.